# Gumby Framework Three Textboxes on on Row?

Tags: forms, validation, frameworks, gumby-framework

This is probably a dumb question but I think the documentation is very lacking on the gumby framework on forms and validation.  How to I get three text boxes on one line correctly.  Everything I've tried the validation carets get all screwed up. I want quantity, product num and des on one row.

While in at it anyone no how to validate zip and phone number using this framework?  I cannot find any documentation on their validation.

```
<dl class="field row">
     <dt class="text"><input name="qty" required type="text" placeholder="Quantity" /></dt>
     <dd class="msg"><span class="caret"></span>Enter quantity.</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="field row">
     <dt class="text"><input name="productnum" required type="text" placeholder="Product Number" /></dt>
     <dd class="msg"><span class="caret"></span>Enter product number.</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="field row">
     <dt class="text"><input name="desription" required type="text" placeholder="Description" /></dt>
     <dd class="msg"><span class="caret"></span>Enter product description.</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually perform validation as I could not get the Gumby validation to work. My jQuery looks like so:

```
// Form validation
$('input').blur(function(){
    if( ($(this).data('form') == 'required') && ( $(this).val() == '' ) ){
        $(this).parents('.field').addClass('error');
    }
});
```

... and my inline fields look like so:

```
<div class="row">                  
  <dl class="field inline textfield">
    <dt class="text">
      <input name="company_phone" type="text" placeholder="Company Phone" data-form="required" />
    </dt>
    <dd class="msg"><span class="caret"></span>Please enter a valid phone number</dd>
  </dl>
...
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

To get the carets to line up nicely, you might want to try wrapping your individual .field elements inside a div.row!

If you decide to go this route, you have a tappable validation function - writing your own regex for matching zip codes might look like so:

```
// Form validation
$('input').blur(function(){
    if( ($(this).attr('name') == 'zipcode') && ( !$(this).val().match(/[0-9]{5}/) ) ){
            $(this).parents('.field').addClass('error');
    }
});
```

But of course that's a very simple example. Good luck :)